# Понижение версии Yii framework при установке пакета

Tags: php, yii2, composer

Пытаюсь установить расширение "smalot/pdfparser" для парсинга pdf файлов. При установке расширения происходит понижение версии Yii framework и всех пакетов - о чем мне и сообщается - "Seems you have downgraded Yii Framework from version 2.0.24 to 2.0.17". Пробовал делать так - composer update smalot/pdfparser и так - composer require smalot/pdfparser. Мой composer.json:

```
{
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
"description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.2.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0",
    "dektrium/yii2-user": "^0.9.14",
    "dektrium/yii2-rbac": "1.0.0-alpha@dev",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2": "dev-master",
    "creocoder/yii2-flysystem": "^0.9.3",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4": "^2.0",
    "beberlei/assert": "^3.2",
    "ramsey/uuid": "^3.8",
    "la-haute-societe/yii2-save-relations-behavior": "^1.7",
    "ocramius/proxy-manager": "^2.2",
    "bower-asset/font-awesome": "^5.8",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
    "ozerich/yii2-filestorage-db": "*",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput": "dev-master",
    "smalot/pdfparser": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
    "codeception/base": "^2.4.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.5.5",
    "codeception/verify": "~1.0.0"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800,
    "fxp-asset": {
        "enabled": false
    }
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
    }
],
"replace": {
    "npm-asset/bootstrap": ">=4.2.1"
}
```

}

Буду признателен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас прописано:

```
"yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.14"
```

Знак `~` тильда означает, текущую, либо следующий "важный" релиз или версию.
Поменяйте на:

```
"yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.22"
```